# Can any one please suggest which sql query is better approach for large data set in mysql

Tags: sql

I have to find the max id row for same group in a table and show the roe details.Using following two approach we can achieve it. But want know which will be good approach for large data. Or any other new approach that will take less time to execute?

Approach 1:

```
select a.* from tab1 a left join (SELECT max(id) as id,name from tab1 
GROUP by name) as tab2 on a.id=tab2.id where a.id=tab2.id
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT id,name from tab1 where id in(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tab1 GROUP by name)
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: according to me these are two good approaches, maybe the second one is a little bit faster. That's what I think at least.

Comment: Why in the first one are you doing a left join and then logically making it an inner join with your where clause? Just make it an inner join.

Comment: Please add the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the manual (13.2.10.11 Rewriting Subqueries as Joins):

A LEFT JOIN can be faster than a subquery because
the server might be able to optimize it better.

So subqueries can be slower than LEFT [OUTER] JOINS, but in my opinion their strength is slightly higher readability. But since there is one LEFT JOIN and a subquery in the first approach, the second approach might be faster at large scale query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a window function to avoid a self-join:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Id DESC) AS IdRankPerGroup
  FROM tab1
) src
WHERE IdRankPerGroup = 1
```

The RANK() function orders each row per "name" group and assigns a ranking based on the "id" value within each group.  Then in the outer query, you just get the rows with a ranking = 1.

Try all three queries, check out the EXPLAIN plans, and see which one works best with large amounts of data.